# Connect to postgres with custom database cluster location with psql

Tags: postgresql

Instead of using `/usr/local/pgsql/data`, I create my database cluster with the following code

```sh
initdb -D /tmp/psql
pg_ctl -D /tmp/psql -l logfile -o "--unix_socket_directories='$PWD'" start
```

But when I run `psql`, I get the following error.

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have read the doc and I cannot find related options for changing the location for database cluster. What have I missed?

Comment: Add to your question the connection string you are using with `psql`. In meantime I'm guessing the issue is you are not using a `-h` in the connection string and `psql` is falling back to the compiled in default for the socket directory. To override this in the connection string see [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS)  under host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and specifying the socket directory with the -h option fixes the issue.

`psql -h $PWD -p 5432 postgres`